# How to use binding parameters in $http service?

Tags: angularjs, httpservice, angular-http, urlbinding

I need to make ajax request. I can do this:

```
var categoryId = 152;
var url = "/someurl/category/"+categoryId;
$http.get(url);
```

Is it possible to use binding with $http? Something like:

```
$http.get("/someurl/category/:categoryId", {categoryId: 152});
```

Comment: Any constructive criticism is welcome

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to accomplish this via binding when concatenation is already easily readable and works, but I've been using tim for a long time under much more complex conditions: https://github.com/premasagar/tim - it's about as lightweight as you can get for simple string templating.

Comment: @Adam is some native method exist?

Comment: You're dealing with a string, a primitive. Here (on the left) are a list of all it's native methods - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String. The `tim` library I pointed you to is a fancy implementation of the `replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

Continuation from my comment:

Example with [tim](http://github.com/premasagar/tim):

```
var url = tim("/someurl/category/{{categoryId}}",{categoryId:152});
$http.get(url);
```